# Difference between "faire plaisir" and "plaire"

Tags: verbes

What is the difference between "faire plaisir" and "plaire"? Example:

- Ça me fait plaisir.
- Ça me plaît.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I say :

> Ton cadeau me fait plaisir et il me plaît.

I'm not being redundant, I express two different ideas.

- Ton cadeau me plaît :
  I'm talking about the present, I like it, I think it's nice, useful, etc.
- Ton cadeau me fait plaisir :
  I'm talking about the gesture involved and not about the nature of the present. I appreciate receiving a gift from you, I'm happy about it. *Faire plaisir* allows you to express an emotion, a feeling.

Comment: So "X me plaît" is not usually understood (literally) as "X pleases me", but rather "I like X" (=J'aime/aime bien X)?

Comment: Precisely.  [To please](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/please) is *faire plaisir*.  *I like it* → Ça me plait.

Comment: 'Plaire' also has that meaning when it comes to people: 'Il me plaît' = 'I like him' ('I am attracted to him').

Comment: Could any of them be used as a polite answer to a "merci" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Not as such. I expect you are thinking of the English [my pleasure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/my%20pleasure). In French we could say  *tout le plaisir est pour moi*, which  I think is more formal than the English "my pleasure". The usual response to a *merci* would be: *Il n'y a pas de quoi* or slightly more formal: *je vous en prie*.